# Do not allow new users to ask question with an external URL

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A post [from this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6406608/fail), which has since been deleted, asked something to the likes of "Hope you can help" with a link to something external of Stack-Overflow.

Now given it was so random, and this was literally a new user with 1 rep, all sorts of alarm bells went off as to what was behind that link. I think in the end it was paste of harry-potter or something, but it could have been something malicious.

I would suggest, as with limiting the ability to comment, that new users are not allowed to post a question with an external URL (outside stack-exchange) until they reach a certain rep level.

Comment: This would be disastrous for [tag:image-processing]. We already bar new users from posting images; links are the only way they have to provide sufficient data for an mcve.

Comment: the downsides to this could be mitigated by having a white-list of acceptable domains for documentation sources or image hosts. (imgur, msdn, wiki, etc), a list that could be automated, i.e. external domains used by >x rep-users in their answers are white-listed. I appreciate now its probably not a good idea though.

Answer (score 13):

As appealing as this is... It would also mean that new users can't link to sources that they quote or link to documentation for further reading on the solutions they provide. It would require that their answers be objectively worse in some key areas, and encourage bad habits that would then have to be unlearned later on.

The system currently requires a modicum of non-link text to go along with a link; I'd be in favor of increasing that, but leaving new authors without the ability to post links *at all* would just hurt the majority for the actions of a few bad actors.

Comment: hmm, yes that is a good point. perhaps a warning then that the link is leaving SO?

Comment: The FR is about questions rather than answers, isn't it? Yet you focus on answers.

Comment: Applies to both, @jan